# Using $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] to pass variables

Tags: php, json

I have a problem. A user is entering two dates in to a form. When the user presses submit, the date is passed to another opened page(1) and doing stuff for DB query.

Can I pass the variables to one more PHP file? To create a JSON file there. I need to create this JSON right after the user hits submit and then redirect to the page(1).

I'm using (GET method) this to redirect and pass the two dates:

```
    header("location:gentable_chart.php?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    exit();
```

I need to pass the variables one more time to create the JSON before the redirect. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: You can use [sessions](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp).

Comment: I'm using sessions. But i need to pass to files two times. One to php file that does not need to see it on client browser. And one after redirect to the page

Comment: You don't "pass" session variables, you just `session_start()` and set a variable on one page, then on the other pages you `session_start()` again and access the variable. Read the link above.

Comment: I'm using session_start() in the two pages. But in the second page there is JS who call php file that makes JSON. In this file i add session_start() but the variables are not saved there...

Comment: Can i pass this two variables to the php script and start him without need to redirect me to page? I need just to generate the json

Comment: Can you give more context? You could use AJAX calls, run redirects, use `include_once`, `file_get_contents` - or make your application modular such that you don't need to "call other files"

Comment: Al i need is first to generate the json that is made by this two dates. And redirect me to another page. I don't know any other approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "JS that calls PHP file", I assume you mean AJAX. In that case, just pass the sessions variables as data:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: 'yourphpfile.php',
    data: 
    {
        var1 : '<?php echo $_SESSION['var1']; ?>',
        var2 : '<?php echo $_SESSION['var2']; ?>'
    },
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(result)
    {   
        // Code
    }
})
```

Then on yourphpfile.php, you can catch the variables like so:

```
$var1 = $_GET['var1'];
$var2 = $_GET['var2'];
```

Comment: Thank for the time to help me. I confused myself. I dont know very well English. I followed one tutorial:https://www.dyclassroom.com/chartjs/chartjs-how-to-draw-line-graph-using-data-from-mysql-table-and-php . In my sql i have: SELECT to_char(TIMESTAMP, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),blok9osx,blok9osy,blok11osx,blok11osy,filblok10,filblok11 FROM otv_fil WHERE TIMESTAMP BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date 23:59:59'  LIMIT $max_results OFFSET $from. This are varibles that i need to fill when call php from js

Comment: How to inject this session variables in yourphpfile.php